# NSTextField and FirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing a cocoa application that has a main window and several panel windows.

I need to autosave some text on a `NSTextField` (which is on a panel window) when user leaves the textfield by clicking the main window etc.  so far I have tried out by implementing resignFirstResponder on a `NSTextField` subclass,however if I click on another textfield on the same window "resignFirstResponder" gets triggered but if I just click on somewhere empty on my main window it does not get triggered. (`NSTextField` loses the blue focus though)

I need to capture this event the `NSTextField` loses  the focus ring to save the uncommitted changes . Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

This text field is on `NSTableCellView`

Answer (score 2):

use `[[NSApp mainWindow] resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: This is the correct and difficult to find answer. It's weird but it is the way. You can call this when focus changes or inside various other delegate methods.

Comment: mmm, how do I know that the focus is changed ? since the sent action on editing end does not fire when I click on my main window.... So Where should I call this ?

Comment: This worked for me. You can also do: self.window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)  If your in a NSView and using swift that is.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the NStextfield's action *sent on end editing*

[image]

Then simply right-click-drag to an object (or FirstResponder) in your Xib file and connect it to a method. It should now run this method when you end the editing (deselect, Enter or Tab).

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but it gets fires on the same occasion as the resign first responder. When I tap somewhere on my main window this does not get fired . At that time the textfield loses the blue focus ring but retains the white editing background. :(